# Power BI - One Master Table with 3 Transaction Tables

Tags: powerbi

I have the tables as per the below diagram

[image: Table Relationships]

There are vouchers in LedgerTrans connected with other 3 tables (but each one is independent of other 2 tables - means a voucher will be available in one of the 3 tables - same voucher won't be available across the 3 Project Trans tables).

I have given the connection as per below and the values are populating in 3 different Matrix visuals for each ProjTrans. The problem I am facing is, all the 3 visuals are summing up to the same amount, though the vouchers are showing correctly in each visual respectively. Is my approach wrong (the connection type)?

The 2nd problem is, I brought in the Project table to keep it as a slicer. The same project could be available in all the 3 ProjTrans. But when I select a project in the slicer, only the table with active connection is getting filtered out. The other 2 matrices are showing blank.

How to achieve active connections for all the 3 ProjTrans tables with a single Project table since Power BI would not allow more than 1 active connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here isn't that Power BI does not allow more than one active connection. What is not allowed is having multiple paths for one table to filter another table since this results in ambiguities. Since you have bidirectional many-to-many relationships from the `fProject` tables to the `fLedgerTrans` table, you would have three distinct paths from `dProject` to `fLedgerTrans` if all your relationships were active.

The quickest fix would be to make all of the many-to-many relationships filter only in one direction (`fLedgerTrans` filters `fProject` tables). Then you should be able to activate the currently inactive relationships.

---

More generally, bidirectional many-to-many relationships are considered bad practice. I'd recommend reading the following article, especially if you don't quite understand what I've explained above:

[Bidirectional relationships and ambiguity in DAX](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/bidirectional-relationships-and-ambiguity-in-dax/)

Comment: Viola... There you go... My bad... After setting the relationship to Unidirection instead of Bidirection, the problem got fixed... Thank you so much... You saved my day...